# Apache: Can I disallow access to a dir except when via a vhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, url

If we assume I have a server called `machinename.ip` which resolves `http://machinename.ip` to default root (`/var/www/html`), and resolves `http://www.example.com`  via vhosts file `www.example.com` to `/var/www/html/example`

Is there an easy way to disallow access to the `/var/www/html/example` folder (and any subdirs/files) **except** via the `www.example.com` vhost? i.e. when via a specific vhost url is added, you can access them, so that `www.example.com` goes to `/var/www/html/example` but `http://machinename.ip/example` or any other combination will not take you there or to any of the sub dirs?

For example for the file `/var/www/html/example/myfile.php`

```
http://www.example.com/myfile.php *yay works*
```

but

```
http://machinename.ip/example/myfile.php *does not*
```

Comment: Why create it as a sub directory and not a true second website?

Comment: basically, while running parallel dirs (or dirs in a "structurally exclusive way") is the "normal" way I want to know how to do it this way - there are reasons beyond the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this like this: in `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

then somewhere inside the `vhosts.conf` file add some `<Directory` markup (like this)

```
<VirtualHost...{blah}
  # | ADD THIS
  # v
  <Directory "/var/www/html/example">
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
  # ^
  # | ADD THIS
  {...blah near where you may have something like...}
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
  ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

you'd have to do these blocks for ALL your vhosts but if you're prepared to put up with that this will do it

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that. Most of the web servers I work with have the default host pointing to `/var/www/default/` and all domains are sent to `/var/www/[domain]`, e.g. `example.com` is at `/var/www/example.com/`.

Default Apache configuration is not like that but you can usually overcome that by  `mkdir -p /var/www/default` and adapting the directory that the default configuration is pointing to.

Comment: thanks, but for my question, I don't want to alter the default root dir, or create a seperate structure. my question is about apache config. I know that going "up" the dir tree is the normal way.